# Elasticsearch 503 error MasterNotDiscoveredException

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ES. I want to add some new nodes in `elasticsearch.yml` file for the same cluster, but I have this error when I try to check the cluster health

```
(GET _cluster/health):
   "error": "MasterNotDiscoveredException[waited for [30s]]",
   "status": 503
```

This is my config file:

```
cluster.name: mycluster6
node.name: "nodeA"
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false

cluster.name: mycluster6
node.name: "nodeB"
node.master: false
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false

cluster.name: mycluster6
node.name: "nodeC"
node.master: false
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false

cluster.name: mycluster6
node.name: "nodeD"
node.master: false
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false

discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
```

in console:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.Utils.extractHostsFromHttpServer(Utils.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ESExporter.openAndValidateConnection(ESExporter.java:344)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ESExporter.openExportingConnection(ESExporter.java:212)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ESExporter.exportXContent(ESExporter.java:275)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ESExporter.exportNodeStats(ESExporter.java:173)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.AgentService$ExportingWorker.exportNodeStats(AgentService.java:305)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.AgentService$ExportingWorker.run(AgentService.java:225)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-05-05 14:00:58,053][TRACE][discovery.zen            ] [nodeD] full ping responses: {none}
[2015-05-05 14:00:58,053][DEBUG][discovery.zen            ] [nodeD] filtered ping responses: (filter_client[true], filter_data[false]) {none}
[2015-05-05 14:00:58,053][TRACE][discovery.zen            ] [nodeD] not enough master nodes [[]]
[2015-05-05 14:00:58,053][TRACE][discovery.zen            ] [nodeD] starting to ping
[2015-05-05 14:01:01,065][TRACE][discovery.zen            ] [nodeD] full ping responses: {none}
[2015-05-05 14:01:01,065][DEBUG][discovery.zen            ] [nodeD] filtered ping responses: (filter_client[true], filter_data[false]) {none}
[2015-05-05 14:01:01,065][TRACE][discovery.zen            ] [nodeD] not enough master nodes [[]]
[2015-05-05 14:01:01,065][TRACE][discovery.zen            ] [nodeD] starting to ping
[2015-05-05 14:01:04,079][TRACE][discovery.zen            ] [nodeD] full ping responses: {none}
[2015-05-05 14:01:04,079][DEBUG][discovery.zen            ] [nodeD] filtered ping responses: (filter_client[true], filter_data[false]) {none}
[2015-05-05 14:01:04,079][TRACE][discovery.zen            ] [nodeD] not enough master nodes [[]]
[2015-05-05 14:01:04,079][TRACE][discovery.zen            ] [nodeD] starting to ping
[2015-05-05 14:01:05,795][ERROR][marvel.agent             ] [nodeD] exporter [es_exporter] has thrown an exception:
```

Comment: Stop all nodes and add the unicast list to each of them: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_important_configuration_changes.html#_prefer_unicast_over_multicast

Comment: Thanks Andrei, I tried to add for all nodes a host, but I have the same problem, but in logs is like this:[2015-05-05 15:09:40,882][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [nodeD] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x4fe76418]], closing connection
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:127)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:644)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:108)

Comment: cluster.name: mycluster6
node.name: "nodeA"
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["nodeA.example.com"]

cluster.name: mycluster6
node.name: "nodeB"
node.master: false
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["nodeA.example.com"]

Comment: Make sure your nodes are reachable by the other nodes...